# Why is my Ubuntu 14.04 stuck in booting mode?

Tags: boot

I am having issues with booting up Ubuntu 14.04 after trying to upgrade to 16.04. I tried using an earlier version under "advanced options" and all in safe mode and get nowhere.

When trying to boot after putting in a password the boot process gets hung up and nothing but the Caps Lock light blinks. When trying under safe mode I get the same as in the picture attached. I also tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> but only get an empty screen with a cursor blinking at the top and I can not type anything in the blank window.

[Picture of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWeoz.jpg)

Picture is not so good so maybe there is a way I could send the error file but I do not know how to do so.

Does anybody have any suggestions.

Results txt info:

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 =>  is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 112 for .

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /dev/sda1 is already mounted or /tmp/BootInfo-7z3uPbhJ/sda1 busy

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext2
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg

sdc2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sdc5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       crypto_LUKS
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 14.5 GiB, 15518924800 bytes, 30310400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *             64     2,991,103     2,991,040  17 Hidden NTFS / HPFS


Drive: sdc _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sdc: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdc1    *          2,048       499,711       497,664  83 Linux
/dev/sdc2             501,758   625,141,759   624,640,002   5 Extended
/dev/sdc5             501,760   625,141,759   624,640,000  83 Linux


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        2016-07-19-21-31-47-00                 iso9660    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS i386
/dev/sdc1        0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce   ext2       
/dev/sdc5        fb8f8978-128c-4ee7-b23f-ec781b89538b   crypto_LUKS 

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sda         /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime)


============================= sdc1/grub/grub.cfg: ==============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
fi
    font="/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_CA
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-403b45af-1749-4d07-942a-d13db711d830' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
    fi
    linux   /vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-403b45af-1749-4d07-942a-d13db711d830' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-36-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-36-generic-advanced-403b45af-1749-4d07-942a-d13db711d830' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-36-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-36-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.4.0-36-generic-recovery-403b45af-1749-4d07-942a-d13db711d830' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.4.0-36-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-4.4.0-36-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-4.4.0-36-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.19.0-68-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.19.0-68-generic-advanced-403b45af-1749-4d07-942a-d13db711d830' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.19.0-68-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.19.0-68-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-3.19.0-68-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.19.0-68-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.19.0-68-generic-recovery-403b45af-1749-4d07-942a-d13db711d830' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.19.0-68-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.19.0-68-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-3.19.0-68-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.19.0-58-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.19.0-58-generic-advanced-403b45af-1749-4d07-942a-d13db711d830' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.19.0-58-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.19.0-58-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-3.19.0-58-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.19.0-58-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.19.0-58-generic-recovery-403b45af-1749-4d07-942a-d13db711d830' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.19.0-58-generic ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.19.0-58-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-3.19.0-58-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
    fi
    knetbsd /memtest86+.elf
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0f98261b-fbe5-41fe-ada6-5309a5a398ce
    fi
    linux16 /memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sdc1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda1

00000000  01 43 44 30 30 31 01 00  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |.CD001..        |
00000010  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |                |
00000020  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  55 62 75 6e 74 75 20 31  |        Ubuntu 1|
00000030  36 2e 30 34 2e 31 20 4c  54 53 20 69 33 38 36 20  |6.04.1 LTS i386 |
00000040  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |        ........|
00000050  00 69 0b 00 00 0b 69 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.i....i.........|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 01 01 00 00 01  |................|
00000080  00 08 08 00 9a 02 00 00  00 00 02 9a 5a 00 00 00  |............Z...|
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5b  00 00 00 00 22 00 23 00  |.......[....".#.|
000000a0  00 00 00 00 00 23 00 08  00 00 00 00 08 00 74 07  |.....#........t.|
000000b0  13 15 1f 2f 00 02 00 00  01 00 00 01 01 00 20 20  |.../..........  |
000000c0  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |                |
*
000001b0  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 58 4f  |              XO|
000001c0  52 52 49 53 4f 2d 31 2e  31 2e 38 20 32 30 31 31  |RRISO-1.1.8 2011|
000001d0  2e 31 31 2e 32 30 2e 31  37 33 30 30 31 2c 20 4c  |.11.20.173001, L|
000001e0  49 42 49 53 4f 42 55 52  4e 2d 31 2e 31 2e 38 2c  |IBISOBURN-1.1.8,|
000001f0  20 4c 49 42 49 53 4f 46  53 2d 31 2e 31 2e 36 2c  | LIBISOFS-1.1.6,|
00000200

Unknown BootLoader on sdc2

00000000  31 cf a8 1c 68 79 f7 78  c0 09 72 d0 cb 05 e1 22  |1...hy.x..r...."|
00000010  a6 54 d9 19 f1 30 e7 4d  d0 aa e2 11 1b 58 78 7d  |.T...0.M.....Xx}|
00000020  30 28 4a 9c 66 df cc c4  38 94 6c 11 e4 4d d4 bb  |0(J.f...8.l..M..|
00000030  77 f4 f0 1e 74 f5 f2 f8  28 14 36 4d e2 63 02 2a  |w...t...(.6M.c.*|
00000040  73 cf 00 17 67 f5 f0 dc  e5 fb 1c f5 fc d7 f0 3c  |s...g..........<|
00000050  d2 70 5e 36 27 a0 98 27  df 92 62 51 ed 2d 6a 2f  |.p^6'..'..bQ.-j/|
00000060  10 96 00 0f 22 80 ce 0f  7b 7f 33 da 31 60 91 c0  |...."...{.3.1`..|
00000070  2e 55 37 98 1c aa 0c 83  f8 fb d7 d2 90 84 72 04  |.U7...........r.|
00000080  62 5b 61 da 46 28 58 22  f7 b6 5c a7 07 33 7c cb  |b[a.F(X"..\..3|.|
00000090  00 04 f8 44 fa 11 a2 a5  b5 d7 a3 13 7f 43 68 22  |...D.........Ch"|
000000a0  db ee b9 76 38 e7 99 a2  e0 55 f3 18 93 98 12 d1  |...v8....U......|
000000b0  a7 21 96 8e d5 4c c9 c1  1a af 58 73 45 4e b7 db  |.!...L....XsEN..|
000000c0  af 96 e1 b2 5e 11 9e 7e  9a b7 fe 3d 2c db 56 bd  |....^..~...=,.V.|
000000d0  e6 a8 c4 74 53 eb 31 d6  2c d7 32 57 21 94 63 51  |...tS.1.,.2W!.cQ|
000000e0  f1 3e 63 3f 20 bb ad a0  c4 65 99 14 a1 8d d6 fa  |.>c? ....e......|
000000f0  fe be 83 d6 82 a1 18 31  02 18 5c cf 31 e2 42 0d  |.......1..\.1.B.|
00000100  9d 76 f7 31 7a 01 68 c3  1d 44 b7 af c0 fe d4 1d  |.v.1z.h..D......|
00000110  12 47 87 43 07 0a 52 81  6a de a6 62 e2 ff 79 4d  |.G.C..R.j..b..yM|
00000120  53 dc ae f9 15 66 21 16  59 84 0c 21 89 4e b6 41  |S....f!.Y..!.N.A|
00000130  4c f6 f0 9a 98 57 2e ef  6b a9 b2 be cc 08 d3 e4  |L....W..k.......|
00000140  10 54 1d 06 e7 61 9d 74  79 22 e4 b6 48 88 82 11  |.T...a.ty"..H...|
00000150  6f bc 68 41 3e 20 9c 81  2a fe 33 67 b9 9e 37 bf  |o.hA> ..*.3g..7.|
00000160  97 76 12 00 92 7c 29 a6  98 fd 65 ed f5 36 2a 42  |.v...|)...e..6*B|
00000170  c1 42 79 b9 7e a9 36 4c  5d 73 50 e9 4e 18 73 cd  |.By.~.6L]sP.N.s.|
00000180  e3 76 96 e6 7f 0f 0c 66  f4 71 28 a4 fe 3e 03 c0  |.v.....f.q(..>..|
00000190  be 4d 40 f9 27 35 8b a4  7d c0 63 d9 d7 a1 67 da  |.M@.'5..}.c...g.|
000001a0  df 0b 59 c4 77 fd ea 42  8f f7 a7 1e 6b 3f b3 ed  |..Y.w..B....k?..|
000001b0  dc b5 b1 ca 83 f5 d8 04  c6 47 08 f0 13 ed 00 3b  |.........G.....;|
000001c0  1d 1f 83 fe ff ff 02 00  00 00 00 40 3b 25 00 00  |...........@;%..|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200

Unknown BootLoader on sdc5

00000000  4c 55 4b 53 ba be 00 01  61 65 73 00 00 00 00 00  |LUKS....aes.....|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  78 74 73 2d 70 6c 61 69  |........xts-plai|
00000030  6e 36 34 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |n64.............|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  73 68 61 31 00 00 00 00  |........sha1....|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 10 00 00 00 00 40  |...............@|
00000070  46 28 2d 18 ca 73 b3 cc  9d e1 2e 6e 12 8e ab 52  |F(-..s.....n...R|
00000080  38 6c b9 7e 22 60 d7 e0  fc 8a 15 2b 68 a3 ac 95  |8l.~"`.....+h...|
00000090  c6 d5 62 ae 15 64 05 58  05 93 08 5f 85 8e 9c 75  |..b..d.X..._...u|
000000a0  28 b5 e2 c3 00 00 7c 06  66 62 38 66 38 39 37 38  |(.....|.fb8f8978|
000000b0  2d 31 32 38 63 2d 34 65  65 37 2d 62 32 33 66 2d  |-128c-4ee7-b23f-|
000000c0  65 63 37 38 31 62 38 39  35 33 38 62 00 00 00 00  |ec781b89538b....|
000000d0  00 ac 71 f3 00 01 f1 76  f2 77 fb 9d da 7b 8e 4c  |..q....v.w...{.L|
000000e0  93 08 8b 66 90 43 c9 c5  ad 3c 96 11 6b ba 30 ee  |...f.C...<..k.0.|
000000f0  c3 ab 85 c2 e3 ec c8 28  00 00 00 08 00 00 0f a0  |.......(........|
00000100  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 02 00 00 00 0f a0  |................|
00000130  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000140  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 03 f8 00 00 0f a0  |................|
00000160  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000170  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 05 f0 00 00 0f a0  |................|
00000190  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 07 e8 00 00 0f a0  |................|
000001c0  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 09 e0 00 00 0f a0  |................|
000001f0  00 00 de ad 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000200


========= Devices which don't seem to have a corresponding hard drive: =========

sdb 

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-7z3uPbhJ/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
```

[image]

Comment: that is a kernel error . boot an old kernel

Comment: Tried to boot an old Kernel and none of the old ones work.

Comment: Hard to tell from the picture you posted. Could be a drive failure. Can you boot a live CD / flash drive and try running boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair . Post the link boot-reapir gives you - "Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs."

Comment: As this happens after Grub I don't see how Boot-Repair can help (it still provides valuable information though). With such aborted or otherwise borked upgrades resulting in kernel panic the only way is to reinstall. That can be done without personal data (or settings) loss by selecting the same partitions used before and NOT ticking format. /home is preserved, software installed *a posteriori* isn't.

Comment: Looks like RAID Boot hooks in init-top or init-bottom or whatever are broken. I'm on my phone... Do you have EnhanceIO, bcache, mdadm, lvm or anything like that setup?

Comment: Ok, it's been a while because my CMOS was locked out and I had to take apart the laptop and so on...I tried running the boot repair but nothing happens. It just says there is no operating system. I thought then that I could install another operating system to run beside it. Doesn't recognize another system so I try to add a partition but it says there is no 'root file' in any of the sections that are displayed. I ran boot infoscript. The results are attached as "Results txt". Please help me just recover the data on the drive at least. Then I can install another operating system.

Comment: Couldn't add it to the comments section so I copied and pasted it to the original question posted.